# Types of DS8K storage configuration with PowerHA

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, aix, high-availability

I am working on DS8K configuration with PowerHA(IBM), but for setting environment of DS8K i am facing issue. The first thing is i am not clear for types of configuration we can do for DS8K, as I got as of now there is two of setting DS8K:

1)Hyper swap

2)Replication

so the confusion is with powerha(IBM) how these setup is different.
Please help me to get understand of these basic knowledge and let me know if any other information is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[High Availability and Disaster Recovery Options for DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247363.pdf) book has an example configuration of PowerHA replication setup, I believe you need replication here as with Db2 and PowerHA we have active/passive setup.